# XML document not well formed

Tags: android, xml

I am not sure why I am getting "The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed". I was trying to use the following code in mainxml under res/menu in an android project. Plese help!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:text="@string/cardHolderName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cardHolderNameInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:text="@string/cardNumber" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cardNumberInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:paddingRight="40sp"
                android:text="@string/expirationDate" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:text="@string/expirationMonth" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/expirationMonthInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:text="@string/expirationYear" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/expirationYearInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:text="@string/cvv" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cvvInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/inputLabel"
                android:text="@string/amount" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/amountInput"
                style="@style/textInput"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:numeric="integer|decimal"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submitAction"
                style="@style/action"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/submit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the only thing in your xml? Post the whole content of the xml document. Also where is the file located and what is the file name?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have your tried cleaning your project? Or copy the contents of the file. Delete the file and remake it then paste it back in there it might fix the problem.

Comment: sorry, the file name is main.xml which is under res/menu folder in an android project.

Comment: As in my answer this is a layout file not a menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a layout file under res/menu. Move the `main.xml` file to `res/layout` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have unclosed elements or haven't included the android namespace. Please post the entire xml doc for further clarification.

Edit:
You have placed your xml under menu instead of under layout.